# how can i order multiple digit string integers numerically and by shortest first? C#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

i have an entity saved on the database that has 2 relevant properties, Code and Number.

the number is just an int between 1 and 99, while the code is a string representation like "01" to "99"

the problem is that some sub-entities have a code like "0103" or "3301", which is just the parent's code + it's own code.

all entities are saved on one table, there are 3 levels of hierarchy indicated only by the length of the code "00" is a level 1, "0000" is level 2, and "000000" is level 3.

I want to order them in such a way that they're presented like

- name - 01
- name - 010201
- name - 0103
- name - 02
- name - 0201
- name - 04

and so on...

where an entity with "01" is first, followed by entities that start with "01" and under each one will be entities that start with "01xx", sort of a tree hierarchy.

note that i'm using EFcore 5, .NET 5, and C# 9

what i have right now is simply

```
var SearchQuery = _appDbContext.Regions.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable().OrderBy(r => r.Code);
```

and then i use that query to generate my DTOs

```
ResultData = await SearchQuery.Select(r => new DTO
                {
                    Id = r.Id,
                    NameCode = r.Name + " - " + r.Code
                }).ToListAsync();
```

should i use a custom comparer or something else? or does this approach satisfy?

Comment: Are you open to changing the design? Assuming SQL Server, it has a built-in type called `hierarchyid` which knows how to store information about tree-like structures and has built in sorting as you describe

Comment: how much is it going to change the design? i'm not familiar with this type
and yes i'm working with SQL server

Comment: If you were to pad with zeroes so all codes were 6 digits then the natural sort order would be as you want - e.g. `010000`, `010201`, `010300`. I'm not sure that it'd be straightforward to do that as part of your query, however.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to pad with zeroes. The sort order is fine without. What you have works (I missed the bit where you implied it does what you want). I'm not sure what the issue is?

Comment: @CharlesMager thank you for the clarification, it seems my problem was that i misunderstood the way `OrderBy(r => r.Code)` works
originally i thought it'll order them like `01`, `02`, and then `01xx` and so on
thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make a function that collects level 1, 2, 3 entities in 3 different Lists (after applying filters) then looping through it less than a couple of times and inserting them to a `List<Entity>` according to the correct order

but @CharlesMager has clarified to me that the normal `OrderBy(r => r.Code)` will have the exact same result due to the Code property not having any whitespaces.

in other words:
`OrderBy(r => r.Code)` will NOT sort the string in `01`, `02`, `01xx`  as I previously thought;
Rather it'll sort them in correct order such as `01`, `01xx`, `02`, `02xx` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Use IComparable :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication20
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] array = {"name - 01", "name - 010201", "name - 0103", "name - 02", "name - 0201", "name - 04"};
            string[] sorted = array.Select(x => new Sort(x)).OrderBy(x => x).Select(x => x.numericStr).ToArray();
        }
    }
    public class Sort : IComparable<Sort>
    {
        public string numericStr { get; set; }
        string[] split { get; set; }
        string number { get; set; }
        public Sort(string input)
        {
            numericStr = input;
            split = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).ToArray();
        }
        public int CompareTo(Sort other)
        {
            int minSize = Math.Min(split.Length, split.Length);
            for(int i = 0; i < minSize; i++)
            {
                int c = split[i].CompareTo(other.split[i]);
                if (c != 0) return c;
            }
            return split.Length.CompareTo(other.split.Length);

        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that this kind of approach requires you to load the entire table into memory and sort after the fact, this cannot be translated to SQL.

Comment: Actually, isn't this just a complicated way of sorting by `Name` then by `Code`? The requirement is only to sort by `Code`, which the original code does a lot more simply.

Comment: @CharlesMager : Original coded wasn't sorting shorter numbers first.

Comment: It was. This does the same. Your sort sorts by 'name' then by '-' then by 'code'.

Comment: @CharlesMager : I know.  Maybe there is a space at end of strings.  Once we know what the exact failure is I will be able to modify my code.  We probably won't be able to fix the original code as easily as with code above.  It sounds like spacing or white character issue.